# Using HtmlUnit how to click (form) a button that isnt a button

Tags: htmlunit

I often encounter buttons, particularly on login forms, that seem to be a series of nested `div`s with a `span` as the final element.

These are rarely part of a form, and I assume controlled by Jvascript.

Is there away to click on these buttons such that the effect of the button's action is achieved, e.g logging into the site and the new page returned?

I have tried waiting for the javascript to load after the page has loaded thus:

```
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(someUrl);
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(6000);
```

then clicking on the `div`s and the `span` and nothing happens.

I am using HtmlUnit 2.36 and I am aware there are some Javascript evalutations issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you can do something similar to this

```
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);


HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(someUrl);
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(6000);

// locate your clickable element
....

buttonLike.click();
// wait until the js has done the job
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(20000);

// now get the current page content based on the current window; using
// HtmlPage myPage = (HtmlPage) buttonLike.click();
// does not work in all cases because the page content might be 
// async replaced by javascript
HtmlPage myPage = (HtmlPage) webClient.getCurrentWindow().getEnclosedPage();
```

Comment: Oddly, the `getPage` returns quite quickly so I didn’t think of extending the Javascript wait.  I will certainly give it a go. Thanks for your responses on all my HtmlUnit questions.

Comment: waitForBack.. is not an option you have to call this every time you like to wait.

Comment: given that there is often a call to `waitForBavkgroundJavaScript` after a `click` perhaps it would be nice to have a new method along side `click` something like `clickThenWaitForBackgroundJavaScript(timeOutInMillis)`  Just a thought